# Multiple selection drop down at once Excel 2013

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down and I want to be able to select multiple values by holding the Shift key from the drop down, I created the drop down by using the Data Validation method in Excel 2013. I have seen many code samples but nowhere is mentioned how can one select multiple items at once and not open the drop down for every selection. Is there a way for this?

Comment: What have you tried? Googling, I found [this page](http://www.contextures.com/excel-data-validation-multiple.html), and [this one](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/544237-allow-multiple-entries-data-validation.html), etc. Do either help? What has worked/hasn't worked?

Comment: I have seen both of these pages, tried them out but not what I am looking for, true you can make multiple selections but you have to open the dropdown every single time. I want to avoid that, by holding the shift key and selecting several items all at once. I am stuck!